# Installation project dynamic connection string

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, connection-string, setup-project

I have a windows forms application, that i want to deploy as installation project using visual studio 2010.

I am using SQLite database and i want to create a connection string while the installation to the installation directory.

On the other hand, i do not know should i attach my empty database to the install project or i have to create it while the installation?

I found lot of web sites, but none of them helped.

Thank you in advance all the help and please refer helper links in this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial which can get you started:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353

Visual Studio is very limited when it comes to the setup project features. It doesn't support SQL connections, so you can do it only through a [custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you need advanced features (like an SQL connection), I recommend a different setup tool:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software